# How do I include Windows 11 in App Insights events

Tags: azure-application-insights

So in App Insights - Events - Operating System we are seeing this

[image]

Now some of our users are on Windows 11 so my first question is where are these showing?

```
Undefined, Other or Windows 10?
```

The script is

```
    let usg_events = dynamic(["*"]);
let mainTable = union pageViews, customEvents, requests
    | where timestamp > ago(1d)
    | where isempty(operation_SyntheticSource)
    | extend name =replace("\n", "", name)
    | where '*' in (usg_events) or name in (usg_events)
;
let queryTable = mainTable;
let cohortedTable = queryTable
    | extend dimension = tostring(client_OS)
    | extend dimension = iif(isempty(dimension), "<undefined>", dimension)
    | summarize hll = hll(itemId) by tostring(dimension)
    | extend Events = dcount_hll(hll)
    | order by Events desc
    | serialize rank = row_number()
    | extend dimension = iff(rank > 5, 'Other', dimension)
    | summarize merged = hll_merge(hll) by tostring(dimension)
    | project ["Operating system"] = dimension, Counts = dcount_hll(merged);
cohortedTable
```

I am new to App Insights and still learning the deeper goodness on offer, can anyone show me how to include Windows 11 please.

Thanks in advance

Kev

Comment: What is the version of your Webapp?

Comment: How you have configured Application insights and where you are checking the results(1st screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Windows 10 and Windows 11 both sohw Windows NT 10.0 in the User-Agent so App Insights thinks that Win 11 is Win 10